Using TypeScript, how do I define a generic, conditional, mapped type that returns a specific type?
I want to write a set of TypeScript types and a function, that takes as input an object of arbitrary depth, where leaf nodes are of the shape { text: string, [key: string]: string } and return an object with the same overall structure, but where leaves are plain strings.
E.g.
const input = {
  button: {
    continue: {
      text: "Continue",
      isTranslated: false
    },
    next: {
      text: "Proceed",
      context: "Button for next screen control"
    }
  },
  error: {
    text: "Unknown error",
    context: "Err message when specific error cause is not known"
  }
};

const output = {
  button: {
    continue: "Continue",
    next: "Proceed"
  },
  error: "Unknown error"
}

The returned type must have the specific keys of the object, as I want to use them to index it.
My eventual use-case is to use the keys of the transformed object to call a function, e.g. getTranslation('button.continue'). I already have a type that will transform object keys into dot notation form, so ignore that here. What I need is to figure out how to map the graphlike structure of arbitrary depth and transform the leaf nodes.
I've tried the following:
 type Graphlike<Leaf> = {
  [key: string]: Graphlike<Leaf> | Leaf;
};

 type Flattened<T, Leaf, FlattenedValue> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Leaf ? FlattenedValue : T[K] extends T ? Flattened<T, Leaf, FlattenedValue> : never;
};


type TranslationLeaf = {
  text: string;
  [key: string]: unknown;
};

type TranslationMap = Graphlike<TranslationLeaf>;

type FlattenedTranslationMap = Flattened<TranslationMap, TranslationLeaf, string>;

function isTranslationLeaf(obj: TranslationLeaf | TranslationMap): obj is TranslationLeaf {
  return "text" in obj;
}

export function simplifyTranslations<T extends TranslationMap>(obj: T): FlattenedTranslationMap {
  const result = {} as FlattenedTranslationMap;

  for (const key in obj) {
    if (isTranslationLeaf(obj[key])) {
      const node = obj[key] as TranslationLeaf;
      // @ts-ignore
      result[key] = node.text;
    } else {
      const node = obj[key] as TranslationMap;
      // @ts-ignore
      result[key] = simplifyTranslations(node);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const output = simplifyTranslations(input);

type ResultantType = typeof output;

However, this returns a resultant type of { [key: string]: never }. Worth noting that the actual JS underneath works as expected. I just need type safety for the keys.

I'm not sure why you have simplifyTranslations return a non-generic return type; presumably that would never work and you really meant to write Flattened<T, TranslationLeaf, string> there in the first place. If so you might want to [edit] so we can focus on the implementation of Flattened.  Then, is this approach what you're looking for?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

You need to use a generic type, can't be a static one.
You can use a recursive type with a conditional type operator to transform only the fields that match your Leaf type.
type FlattenedTranslationMap<T extends TranslationMap> = {
  [K in keyof T]: 
    // check if it's a Leaf structure
    // infer the text in case it is a constsnt and not just a generic string
    T[K] extends {text: infer Text extends string}
      // use inferred value
      ? Text 
      // check if it's a nested map
      : T[K] extends TranslationMap
        // recursively apply same transformations to it and it's children 
        ? Simplified<FlattenedTranslationMap<T[K]>>
        // if none of the abole leave untouched
        : T[K];
}


type Output = FlattenedTranslationMap<Input>
/*
type Output = {
    button: {
        continue: string;
        next: string;
    };
    error: string;
}
*/

Playground
